# How to generate validations for check constraint in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm in a database first scenario, so EF generates the entity classes from the existing database, the tables in my db have many check constrains that validate that the inserted/updated values meet specific criteria, my problem is that EF doesn't generate any code for these constraint, so these constraints will be checked only in the database. What I want is to make these validations from the generated classes so if there's an error it will be raised without going to the database.

I know that I can modify the T4 template for my model so I add my constraints to the generated classes, but any code I will write will be hard coded for each specific table in hand based on the template of the constraint code, what I need is a solution that adapt the generation with any shape or template of the constraint code.
To explain more, here is 2 samples of 2 different constraints I have:

```
([ADT_OPT_UPD]>=(0) AND [ADT_OPT_UPD]<=(2))
([INS_USR]>=(0))
```

These are 2 samples of the constraints I have in my database, and it can get more complicated by adding more ANDs ORs and so on, so I need a generation method that adapts with whatever the template of the check constraint is.

I was thinking about writing a parser that parse the constraint and generate the equivalent C# code, but such parser would need to handle all the possible cases for the shape of the constraint code and that's too much for me to do now as I have no time for it. So is there any other solution, and if this the only way to do it, is there any tool or library that can help me in this task?